# C++ - Representing ownership via pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, ownership, nullptr

In my game engine, there are three classes: *EntityCharacter*, *EntityVehicle* and *EntityVehicleSeat*.

[image]

*EntityVehicle* contains seat objects with pointers to instances of *EntityCharacter*. If seat object's target character entity pointer is a null pointer, no character is sitting on that specific seat object. EntityCharacter-class instances have also pointers to seat objects, indicating, whether these character entities are sitting in some vehicles or not.

In other words, EntityCharacter-class instance has a pointer to EntityVehicleSeat and the other way around:

```
EntityCharacter -> EntityVehicleSeat
EntityCharacter <- EntityVehicleSeat
```

This way we can check this ownership via both character and vehicle entity.

It would be simple to set pointers to point to each other, but there's one problem - if the other object falls out of scope, we end up having an invalid pointer in the remaining object.

[image]

*How can one represent this kind of ownership sophisticatedly? How can the other object be informed about the fact that the other object no longer exists?*

Comment: Use notification on destructor.

Comment: could you use destructor to notify the other object?

Comment: Is this just a 1:1 relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managing object-to-object relationships, including bidirectional ones, is where destructors become helpful. You can eliminate the problem of dangling pointers like this:

```
~EntityCharacter() {
    // Do some other cleanup...
    ...
    if (seatPtr) {
        assert(seatPtr->characterPtr == this); // That's my seat!
        seatPtr->characterPtr = NULL;
    }
}

~ EntityVehicleSeat() {
    // Do some other cleanup...
    ...
    if (characterPtr) {
        assert(characterPtr->seatPtr == this); // That's my character!
        characterPtr->seatPtr = NULL;
    }
}
```

One problem with this approach is concurrency: if a seat and a character can be deleted simultaneously from different threads, you would need to synchronize deletions.

Comment: So easy yet so handy. Thanks a lot!